# How do I find where a php var or constant has been set?

Tags: php

This php script I'm working on has a million includes and I'm trying to find where the constant TEXT_PRODUCT has been defined (what filename and line number) is this possbile?

Comment: is it `TEXT_PRODUCT` or `$TEXT_PRODUCT?` as that may give you a clue as constants are (mostly) defined early

Comment: With `grep` maybe: http://unixhelp.ed.ac.uk/CGI/man-cgi?grep

Comment: I think any IDE can make it possible and very easy. See variants: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6166/any-good-php-ide-preferably-free-or-cheap

Comment: TEXT_PRODUCT, I've checked the beginning of the code already. I was just wondering if there is a debug feature to see the code where the var or constant was instantiated. Thanks

Comment: Most IDEs offer variable definition lookup. The common method is: hold CTRL and click the variable. If your IDE can't do this: either get an IDE that can or use a tool like grep or a similar "find in files" tool. In all seriousness, a good IDE boosts your performance, get your employer to buy a license for you if necessary (I'm totally serious).

Comment: @Felix What makes you think that he is on Linux? :P

Comment: @Chris: Is there something else than Linux? :P ;)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

if you want to check for one time where it gets defined, define TEXT_PRODUCT at start of your script as. So whenever PHP script tries to define it again in any file it will give notice level error that it is defined previously.
But you have to define your own error handler to get exact line number and file

```
     <?php

     function customeHandler($errno, $errstr, $errfile, $errline){
         echo "<b>My NOTICE</b> [$errno] $errstr<br />\n";
         echo "At line ", $errline , "<br />";
         echo "At file ", $errfile , "<br />";;
             return true;
      }

      $old_error_handler = set_error_handler("customeHandler");

      define("TEST",3);
```

So whenever, we again define same variable in any file, it will display notice level error on screen and you can get file name as well as line no. using this.

Answer (score 3):

```
grep -r 'define("TEXT_PRODUCT"' *
```