# How can I tell in what 'required' file a define() constant was defined, in php?

Tags: php, constants, require

I'm working on a larger project with a lot of autoloaded files.
There are several files which purely define a bunch of global constants like this:

```
define("CONSTANT_ONE", "constant one value");
define("CONSTANT_TWO", "constant two value");
...
```

some of these file require other similar files.
I need to identify at runtime the constants that were included form one of these nested required files full of defines.

I'm looping through all define's using get_defined_constants().

currently I'm identifying which ones come from `defines_i_want.php` by reading that file into a string using `file_get_contents('defines_i_want.php')` and using `str_contains()` to check if my constant exists there.
This feels pretty hacky to me.  Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How do I find where a php var or constant has been set?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6164494/how-do-i-find-where-a-php-var-or-constant-has-been-set)

Comment: `grep -r CONSTANT_ONE ./ | grep 'define('` but I'd wager that you're accidentally including the file that defines them more than once.